# Is there a way to halt a process that opens a new socket?

Tags: linux, networking

I'd like something to pause a process whenever it tries to open a new socket. Is there any way to do this in an event driven manner in linux?

Off the top of my head I was thinking you could periodically check for new sockets with ss and send sigstop to the process but this seems hacky and I'd like an event driven solution so that the process is stopped before any data is written/read.

Comment: Is this possibly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What problem exactly are you trying to solve that you believe this approach would help with? In case there are other/better ways to solve the underlying problem it would be good to describe the root issue.

Comment: If it turns out you still want/need this approach you need to give us more info on the constraints of what you can do. For example, are you able to change the process code or do you have to treat it as a black box? Do you have root access or is it only for processes owned by you?

Comment: I'm working on a toy project for a process based firewall. One of the features I'd like is a whitelist where new processes are not able to open sockets until added to said whitelist. So I would halt the process, decide what to do, then continue the program after the decision is made.

Comment: Root access is fine, but I would like to treat all processes as a black box. This should work generally for any program needing network access.

Comment: If "firewall", just close all traffic and open up on a case by case basis. If you want to handle security, check out *and understand* the security harness for you distribution (normally SELinux).